# Is it "we kept a safe distance from each other" or "we kept a safe distance away from each other"

Tags: expressions

Is "we kept a safe distance away from each other" incorrect or less correct than "we kept a safe distance from each other"?

First time asking on this stack exchange -- apologies if I am not adding enough detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we kept a safe distance from 'one another'. as opposed to 'each other'. no need for 'away'. its already stated by the use of 'distance'

Comment: "Traditionally, each other refers to two people and one another refers to more than two people, but this distinction is disappearing in modern English." [Source](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/reciprocal-pronouns-each-other-and-one-another)

Comment: one and another = one another